Cannot find Ubuntu App Center after installing KDE plasma
I installed and set up KDE Plasma with the latest version of Ubuntu 24.04. Everything went smoothly, so I downloaded some software like VS Code, Sublime Text editor, and a few other packages. They were working fine until I decided to reboot the system. After logging into Plasma again, I noticed that all the software and packages I had installed were gone. I checked the Ubuntu App Center, but it wasn't there either.
I tried to install it using the command:
sudo apt install gnome-software

which seemed to run successfully as shown in this screenshot:

However, even after that, I couldn't find App Center.
In the image below you can see that when I am searching for VS Code nothing shows up and also looks like KDE has replaced App Center's name with Discover:

There is an Installed section there where I can see that VS Code is installed as shown in this screenshot:
.
Could someone please help me understand what's happening and how to fix this issue? I'm new to Linux, having recently switched from Windows.

You have got a new desktop with new/different features, you need to learn how it works, you can star by pushing the buttons at the bottom left hand side of your screen.

One can install it by: sudo snap install snap-store, more info: https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-store-app .
